# Advice graphics in latex document

Tags: graphics

I have to save many plots from matlab and put it in my thesis. Which is better? Save them as pdf and therefore a vectorial image that does not lose too much quality but large dimension (even if in my case is 10kb for each graph), or as png?

Comment: In my opinion, PDF is better since you can resize without loss quality.

Comment: Depending on what you're plotting, you could also save the data to be plotted and have latex plot it for you (using pgfplots), this has the advantages of latex controlling fonts and the ability to use latex natively on axis etc.

Comment: I never use this function, but it could also help me solve some problems with a matlab plot which even if the scale and the axis are the same, it plots me one axis with a spacing sample and the other one with another spacing salmple. In this way I might solve this problem here...
For the other plots I always saved them as pdf for the reason that Sigur   explained